# Setting 3rd Level Nested Attribute on a Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm having trouble changing the location $id on this Backbone model.

```
{
"approved": null,
"caption": "This is my photo!",
"created": 1393537913,
"location": {
        "_id": {
                "$id": 5
        },
        "address1": "155 West Street",
        "city": "Bangkok",
        "country": "THA",
        "latitude": "13.136",
        "longitude": "100.2068",
        "postalCode": "10330",
        "region": "AP"
        }
}
```

I've tried:

```
model.set({"location":{"_id":{"$id": 6}}})
```

But that obviously overwrites the entire location object.

```
model.set({"location._id":{"$id":6}})
```

Creates a new attribute on the model, "location._id".

So, how can I dig in to the location to change that attribute?

Comment: Why are you having to set the _id field? In general, you shouldn't have to mess with that.

Comment: I need to update the location associated with this "photo" model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
var location = model.get('location');
location._id = { "$id": 6 };
```